# Google cloud messaging's setRegisteredOnServer() function.

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

In GCM, why everytime after the device sends parameter to the server, it will then call `setRegisteredOnServer(Context context, boolean flag)` , in the documentation it says this function **Sets whether the device was successfully registered in the server side.** I don't get the point of this function, could anyone explain it?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [GCMRegistrar code](http://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/gcm-client/src/com/google/android/gcm/GCMRegistrar.java#411) I can see that all it does is set a local property, which can then be retrieved by isRegisteredOnServer. This property is private and neither of these methods are referenced anywhere else in the GCM helper classes, so I can only assume that they are a convenient way to tell your application when GCM is available. This would be useful if you had to include 3rd party libraries that depended on GCM connectivity and needed a standard way to test for it, but I'll admit it's a very speculative use-case.